# C++ Eigen's SelfAdjointEigenSolver not faster with zeros in matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigenvector

Most eigenvector solvers focus on [*diagonalizing* a matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDiagonalization.html) via rotations (e.g. [Givens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) or Jacobi rotations) so I would assume that if there were already numerous zeros in the input matrix that the solver would be faster (i.e. the more zeros off the diagonal, the closer the matrix is to being diagonal). This does not seem to be the case with [C++ Eigen's `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html).

Below is a test program where I generate a random 632 x 632 matrix `A` (only the lower triangular part of the matrix is processed since the matrix is assumed to be symmetric). I first zero out some percentage of the matrix and then time 100 calls to `eigenSolver.compute(A)`. The number of zeros do not seem to have an affect until `A` becomes a purely diagonal matrix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 632;
    Eigen::MatrixXf A = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(N,N);

    constexpr float zeroRate = 0.75;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
        for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
            double number = distribution(generator);
            if (number <= zeroRate)
                A(i,j) = A(j,i) = 0;
        }

    Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eigenSolver(N);
    
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        eigenSolver.compute(A); // only lower triangle processed
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "eigenSolver.compute() runtime: " << duration << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Run times (3.2 GHz Intel Core i5, `g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++11`):

```
zero rate    time
---------   -------
   0.00      11986 ms
   0.50      11946 ms
   0.75      11526 ms
   0.90      11886 ms
   0.95      11901 ms
   1.00       3438 ms
```

Can someone give me insight as to why I am not getting faster run times for more zeros?

Comment: If you follow the links in the documentation, you'll notice that Eigen brings the matrix to tridiagonal form using Householder-reflections (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Tridiagonalization.html#acd288abb081d3b40b87e4b98cd8f6ee9) -- this does not (or barely) profit from zeroes in the input matrix.

Comment: For the matrices I am dealing with I have found ways to permute them into a block diagonal form -- some of the blocks are large, but many are small. There are still spurious non-zero values outside these blocks. I guess I was hoping there was a way to exploit this structure. If they were purely block diagonal then I can compute the eigenvectors on the blocks themselves. It does seem like many of the Householder transformation could be avoided, but alias I guess not. Is there a solver the benefits having lots of zeros for large matrices? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You could manually remove the off-block elements with Givens/Jacobi-Rotations, apply the Tridiagonalization on each block separately, then get the Eigenvalues from the resulting tridiagonal matrix (also possibly doing it block-wise if some blocks are still separated). Maybe also first tridiagonalize the blocks, then remove off-elements (IDK what is more efficient in your case)